# Decide where to edit Web.Config's HttpRuntime maxRequestLength

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-config

Scenario:-  I have clientApp that is an HTML VS2012 Solution, which interacts with the WEB API, that is Self Host (Its a different solution in VS 2012).

On a Page(HTML) I am providing a popup for user to update the Web.config's httpruntime maxrequestlength of the client App. It calls the API through Javascript, then I save the edited string into the database.

Problem :- 
1) Second Task is to update the Web.Config which has tag httpRuntime with the edited value from the user. 
2) These 2 being different solution one cannot access other's web config.

What are the ways to get this thing done?

> ```
> In Client App (HTML) :- 
> <configuration>
> <system.web>
> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
> <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" **maxRequestLength="1048576"**/>    </system.web>
> ...
> </configuration>
> ```

**Edit :-** Please suggest if anyother way should implemented.

**Edit:- **Is there anyway to update the web config at the runtime of one application from another application which are on yhe same server. But the one whoms we are going to edit is.. Is the hosted web site.

Comment: Good luck working that one out

Comment: Thanks!!  Any suggestion are welcome Coulton!